# Código javascript está dando erro

Tags: javascript, asp

Postei uma thread [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80683/qual-alternativa-para-substituir-c%C3%B3digos-em-asp-por-javascript/80695#80695) que tratava de como substituir um código ASP por Javascript mais limpo. Bem, tive muita ajuda, do Maicon e do TobyMosque. Bem, fiz as devidas alterações, ao meu entender e dá um erro que eu não consegui eliminar. Veja abaixo o código ASP com JS misturado a ser substituído:

```
function selecionar(num_seq_proposta_ts, num_proposta, nome_titular){
    var txt_chamada = '';
    try {
        var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
        txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
        var aux = oMyObject.document;
    } 
    catch (e){
        txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
    }   
    var txt_prefixo = '';
    var txt_sufixo  = '';

    //Somente joga o valor para o campo se ele existir
    <%if trim(nome_campo_cod_ts)<> "" then%>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);    
            <%end if%>
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        }
    <% else %>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_pj_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_pj_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        }
    <%end if%>  

    <%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
        if (onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts != null ) {
            onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
        }
    <%else%>
        if (onum_seq_proposta_ts != null ) {
            onum_seq_proposta_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
        }
    <%end if %>

    <%if trim(nome_campo_tit)<>"" then%>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_tit%>' + txt_sufixo);
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_tit%>' + txt_sufixo);
        }
    <%else %>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_proposta_pj    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_proposta_pj' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_proposta' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>          
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_proposta_pj    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_proposta_pj' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_proposta' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>  
        }
    <%end if %>

    <%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
        if (onum_proposta_pj != null ) {
            onum_proposta_pj.value = num_proposta;
            <%if indOrigem = "J" then%>
                onum_proposta_pj.onchange();
            <%end if%>
        }
    <%else%>
        if (onum_proposta != null ) {
            onum_proposta.value = num_proposta;
            <%if indOrigem = "J" then%>
                onum_proposta.onchange();
            <%end if%>
        }
    <%end if%>

    <%if trim(nome_campo_prop)<>"" then%>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            var onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_prop%>' + txt_sufixo);
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            var onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_prop%>' + txt_sufixo);
        }
    <% else %>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            var onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>nome_titular' + txt_sufixo);
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            var onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>nome_titular' + txt_sufixo);
        }
    <% end if %>

    if (onome_titular != null )
        onome_titular.value = stringReplace(nome_titular, "|*|", "'");


    <%if trim(funcao_executar) <> "" then%>
        try{
            var aux = eval(txt_chamada + ".<%Response.Write funcao_executar%>");                
        }catch(e){
            window.returnValue = 'window.<%Response.Write funcao_executar%>';           
        }
    <%end if%>

    <% if ucase(indsubmit) = "TRUE" then %>
        eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.submit()");
    <%end if%>
    parent.self.close();
}
```

Esse é o código que eu fiz. O colega TobyMosque me sugeriu uma abordagem, para evitar os `eval` mas não consegui fazer, dava erro. Deixei o `eval`, tentar fazer funcionar primeiro e depois tento melhorar o código. Veja o que eu fiz:

```
    var asp = {};
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "ind_tipo_proposta_pj", { value: "<%= ind_tipo_proposta_pj %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "prefixo", { value: "<%= prefixo %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "nome_campo_cod_ts", { value: "<%= nome_campo_cod_ts %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "nome_campo_tit", { value: "<%= nome_campo_tit %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "indOrigem", { value: "<%= indOrigem %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "nome_campo_prop", { value: "<%= nome_campo_prop %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "funcao_executar", { value: "<%= funcao_executar %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });

//------------------------------------------------------------------------   
function selecionar(num_seq_proposta_ts, num_proposta, nome_titular){
    //Adequação para chamada modal dentro do chrome
    var txt_prefixo = '';
    var txt_sufixo  = '';
    var txt_chamada = "";
    var onome_titular = '';
    var janela = null;

    if (window.dialogArguments) {
        janela = window.dialogArguments;
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
    } else if (window.parent.opener) {
        janela = window.parent.opener;
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
    } else {
        janela = window.parent.dialogArguments;
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
    }

    if (janela) {
        var form01 = null;

        if (janela.document) {
            form01 = janela.document.form01;
        }
        else {
            form01 = janela.elements;
        }

        var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = null;
        var onum_seq_proposta_ts = null;
        var onum_proposta = null;
        var onum_proposta_pj = null;

        var nome_campo_cod_ts_id = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>";
        var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts_id = "<%= trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj)%>" == "S";

        window["objeto"] = null;

        if(nome_campo_cod_ts_id != ""){
            if(asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj == "S")
                onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts + txt_sufixo);
            else
                onum_seq_proposta_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts + txt_sufixo);
        }
        else
        {
            if(asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj == "S")
                onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + num_seq_proposta_pj_ts + txt_sufixo);
            else
                onum_seq_proposta_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + num_seq_proposta_ts + txt_sufixo);
        }

        if (asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj == "S"){
            if (onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts != null ) {
                onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (onum_seq_proposta_ts != null ) {
                onum_seq_proposta_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
            }
        }

        if(nome_campo_tit != ""){
            onum_proposta = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
        }
        else
        {
            if(asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj == "S")
            {
                onum_proposta_pj = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + num_proposta_pj + txt_sufixo);
            }
            else
            {
                onum_proposta = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + num_proposta + txt_sufixo);
            }
        }

        if (asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj == "S"){
            if (onum_proposta_pj != null ) {
                onum_proposta_pj.value = num_proposta;
                if(asp.indOrigem == "j")
                {
                    onum_proposta_pj.onchange();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (onum_proposta_pj != null ) {
                onum_proposta.value = num_proposta;
                if(asp.indOrigem == "j")
                {
                    onum_proposta.onchange();
                }
            }
        }

        if(asp.nome_campo_prop != "")
        {
            onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_prop + txt_sufixo);
        }
        else
        {
            onome_titular   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + nome_titular + txt_sufixo);
        }

        if (onome_titular != null )
            onome_titular.value = stringReplace(nome_titular, "|*|", "'");

        if (funcao_executar != "")
        {
            if (window.dialogArguments || window.parent.dialogArguments) {
                var aux = eval(txt_chamada + "." + asp.funcao_executar);
            }
            else
            {
                window.returnValue = "window." + asp.funcao_executar;
            }

        }

    }//Fim janela

    try
    {
        window.parent.dialogWindow.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        parent.self.close();
    }

    //<% if ucase(indsubmit) = "TRUE" then %>
    //  eval(txt_chamada + ".document.form01.submit()");
    //<%end if%>
    //parent.self.close();
}
```

Esse é o erro que está dando:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Esse é o que o debug trouxe nesse erro

> .document.form01.3753742

O número é o número de cadastro de uma pessoa que a pesquisa retorna. O que está errado?

Faltou carregar a var `txt_chamada`:

```
if (window.dialogArguments) {
        janela = window.dialogArguments;
        txt_chamada = 'window.dialogArguments';
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
    } else if (window.parent.opener) {
        janela = window.parent.opener;
        txt_chamada = 'window.parent.opener';
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
    } else {
        janela = window.parent.dialogArguments;
        txt_chamada = 'window.parent.dialogArguments';
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
    }
```

Agora o erro que dá é esse:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

TobyMosque, deixa-me esclarecer algo aqui. Essa chamada:

```
if (asp.nome_campo_tit) {}
    try {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    } catch (e) {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    }
}
```

Com essa chamada o form não abre Modal no Chrome. Foi necessário fazer isso:

```
if (window.dialogArguments) {
            janela = window.dialogArguments;
        } else if (window.parent.opener) {
            janela = window.parent.opener;
        } else {
            var janela = window.parent.dialogArguments;
        }
```

Logo farei essa alteração, para adequar a minha necessidade. O nosso trampo aqui é exatamente esses form ou frame abrirem de forma Modal no Chrome. Isso acontece apenas no IE.

Fiz essa alteração e resolveu. Obrigado ao Toby e ao Maicon.

```
function selecionar(num_seq_proposta_ts, num_proposta, nome_titular) {
        var janela = window.dialogArguments || window.parent.opener || window.parent.dialogArguments;

        if (janela) {
            var form01 = null;
            if (janela.document) {
                form01 = janela.document.form01;
            }
            else {
                form01 = janela.elements;
            }
            var container = form01 || janela.document.all;

            var onum_seq_proposta_ts = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts];
            var onum_proposta = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit];
            var onome_titular = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_prop]

            if (onum_seq_proposta_ts != null) {
                onum_seq_proposta_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
            }
            if (onum_proposta != null) {
                onum_proposta.value = num_proposta;
                if (asp.indOrigem === "J") {
                    onum_proposta.onchange();
                }
            }
            if (onome_titular != null) {
                onome_titular.value = stringReplace(nome_titular, "|*|", "'");
            }

            var aux = null;
            if (asp.funcao_executar) {
                if (janela[asp.funcao_executar]) {
                    aux = janela[asp.funcao_executar]();
                } else if (window[asp.funcao_executar]) {
                    window.returnValue = window[asp.funcao_executar]()
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            window.parent.dialogWindow.close();
        }
        catch (e) {
            parent.self.close();
        }

        //if (asp.indsubmit && janela.document.form01) {
        //    janela.document.form01.submit();
        //}
        parent.self.close();
    }
```

Comment: pnet, o problema do `eval()` é justamente a dificuldade de depurar o mesmo, então tente fazer um wrapper para o eval como no seguinte [exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/auys9Lka/), no lugar de chamar o `eval()` chame o método `debugEval()` como no exemplo e veja se o script está sendo montado da forma correta.

Comment: @TobyMosque, ok vou fazer isso. Eu não fechei o post anterior porque ainda não consegui fazer funcionar. Aquela abordagem que você passou, não consegui fazer, declarando o window["objeto"]...

Comment: @TobyMosque, lembrei-me de algo aqui. A minha situação é essa: Faço minhas alterações em minha máquina local, salvo, copio o formulário que eu alterei, aí colo no servidor  e rodo. Esse servidor não tenho como pegar log e etc...

Comment: dá uma olhada nesta minha [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81402/2363), especialmente na parte que tem o comentario `//conteudo.contentWindow.opener = window;`, talvez fazendo isto resolva os eu problema de compatibilidade entre o chrome e o IE (dialog vs popup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pnet, acho que você não entendeu muito bem a minha sugestão, vou postar aqui um protótipo do seu código com as alterações propostas:

**arquivo.asp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "<%= trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) %>";
    asp.indOrigem = "<%= trim(indOrigem) %>";

    asp.complemento = asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj === "S" ? "_pj" : "";    
    asp.prefixo = "<%= trim(prefixo) %>";
    asp.nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "num_seq_proposta" + asp.complemento + "_ts";
    asp.nome_campo_tit = "<%= trim(nome_campo_tit) %>" || "num_proposta" + asp.complemento;
    asp.nome_campo_prop = "<%= trim(nome_campo_prop) %>" || "nome_titular";
    asp.funcao_executar = "<%= trim(funcao_executar) %>";
    asp.indsubmit = "<%= trim(ucase(indsubmit)) %>" === "TRUE";
</script>
```

**arquivo.js**

```
function selecionar(num_seq_proposta_ts, num_proposta, nome_titular){    
    var janela = window.dialogArguments || window.parent.opener;    
    var container = janela.document.form1 || janela.document.all;   

    var onum_seq_proposta_ts = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts];
    var onum_proposta = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit];
    var onome_titular = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_prop]

    if (onum_seq_proposta_ts != null ) {
        onum_seq_proposta_ts.value = num_seq_proposta_ts;
    }
    if (onum_proposta != null ) {
        onum_proposta.value = num_proposta;
        if (indOrigem === "J") {
            onum_proposta.onchange();
        }
    }
    if (onome_titular != null ) {
        onome_titular.value = stringReplace(nome_titular, "|*|", "'");
    }

    var aux = null;
    if (asp.funcao_executar) {
        if (typeof janela[asp.funcao_executar] === "function") {
            aux = janela[asp.funcao_executar]();
        } else if(typeof window[asp.funcao_executar] === "function") {
            window.returnValue = window[asp.funcao_executar]()
        }
    }

    if (asp.indsubmit && janela.document.form1) {}
        janela.document.form1.submit();
    }
    parent.self.close();
}
```

**Explicações**

Ao meu ver, o mais importante é tentar desacoplar ao máximo o `script` da página `asp`, assim como evitar repetição de código e por fim remover o uso de exceções como controle de fluxo.

Para tentar alcançar estes objetivos tomei algumas decisões, começando por dividir o `script` em 3 partes:

1. declarações das variáveis vindas do servidor que serão usadas no script no `arquivo.asp`.
2. declaração das variáveis locais e globais já no `arquivo.js`.
3. corpo do algoritmo.

Então em primeiro momento procurei e listei todas as marcações `ASP` (`<% valor %>`) no script e as movi para o cabeçalho da página `asp`, por exemplo, o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<%if trim(nome_campo_tit)<>"" then%>
    try {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_tit%>' + txt_sufixo);
    } catch (e) {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_tit%>' + txt_sufixo);
    }
<%else %>
```

movemos as declarações `ASP` `<%Response.Write prefixo%>`, `<%Response.Write nome_campo_tit%>` para o cabeçalho da página

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    ...   
    asp.prefixo = "<%= trim(prefixo) %>";
    asp.nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>";
    ...
</script>
```

e o script ficou assim:

```
if (asp.nome_campo_tit) {}
    try {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    } catch (e) {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    }
}
```

depois analisei os blocos `try-catch` que estão sendo utilizados para controlar o fluxo do `script`, então o `try` foi substituído por um `if` que verifica se a condição que provoca o erro não irá acontecer e o `catch` pelo `else`, vamos tomar como exemplo o seguinte bloco:

```
try {
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
    var aux = oMyObject.document;
} 
catch (e){
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
}
```

o erro que pode acontecer aqui, é acessar uma propriedade de `window.dialogArguments` quando o mesmo é `undefined`, como `if(undefined)` é avaliado como falso, podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
if (window.dialogArguments) {
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
} else {
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
}
```

note que removemos o `aux`, pois a sua única utilidade era provocar o erro.

agora vamos verificar as condições, vamos pegar um `if` para estudar:

```
if (asp.nome_campo_tit) {}
    try {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    } catch (e) {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
    }
} else {
    try {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
        txt_sufixo  = '';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + "nome_titular" + txt_sufixo);
    } catch (e) {
        txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
        txt_sufixo  = '\']';
        var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + "nome_titular" + txt_sufixo);
    }
}
```

o que muda no bloco do `if` para o `else`, é que caso o `asp.nome_campo_tit` for igual a vazio, o script utiliza um valor padrão, no caso "nome_titular", então por que não fazer um `else` com a variável `asp.nome_campo_tit`? Para tal vamos atualizar o cabeçalho da página:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    ...   
    asp.nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>";
    ...
</script>
```

ficou assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    ...   
    asp.nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "nome_titular";
    ...
</script>
```

isto é possível, pois o valor padrão de um `type` é avaliado como `false` em uma comparação, então `if ("")` resulta em `false`, assim como `var str = "" || "alt"` vai resultar em `str = "alt"`, enquanto que `var str = "teste" || "alt"` em `str = "exemplo"`, desta forma `asp.nome_campo_tit` sempre terá um valor, e podemos simplificar o `script`:

```
try {
    txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
    txt_sufixo  = '';
    var onum_proposta = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
} catch (e) {
    txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
    txt_sufixo  = '\']';
    var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
}
```

ainda temos o problema do `eval`, mas para resolver precisamos entender o que as variáveis `txt_chamada`, `txt_prefixo` e `txt_sufixo` fazem...

`txt_chamada` contém a referência para a janela que contém os `input`:

```
var txt_chamada = "";
if (window.dialogArguments) {
    var oMyObject = window.dialogArguments;
    txt_chamada = "oMyObject";
} else {
    txt_chamada = "window.parent.opener";
}
```

no lugar de armazenamos o texto para montar um `script` a ser executado pelo `eval()`, vamos armazenar a janela propriamente dita:

```
var janela = window.dialogArguments || window.parent.opener;
```

note que se `janela` recebe `window.parent.opener` apenas se `window.dialogArguments` for `undefined`

`txt_prefixo` recebe o `txt_chamada + ".document.form1"` pertencente a nossa janela, caso `form1` seja `undefined` ele irá usar o `txt_chamada + ".document.all"`.

```
try {
    txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
    txt_sufixo  = '';
    var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
} catch (e) {
    txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
    txt_sufixo  = '\']';
    var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
}
```

note que ele usa novamente um bloco `try-catch` para definir o controle de fluxo, o erro aqui ocorre quando o `script` tenta acessar uma propriedade de `form1` quando o mesmo não existe, então podemos simplificar para o seguinte:

```
var container = janela.document.form1 || janela.document.all;
```

`txt_sufixo` recebe o fechamento de um parêntese, caso `txt_prefiro` abra um, como não iremos acessar as propriedades do `containe`r através do `eval()`, ele é desnecessário.

vale lembrar que posso acessar os `input` do `container`, independente dele receber `form1` e do `all` através do nome do `input` da seguinte forma: `container[nome_input]`, desta forma a linha abaixo:

```
var onum_proposta   = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit + txt_sufixo);
```

é equivalente ao seguinte:

```
var onum_proposta   = container[asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_tit];
```

e por fim, algumas verificações de segurança antes de chamar alguma função com nome dinâmico:

```
if (typeof janela[asp.funcao_executar] === "function") { 
    janela[asp.funcao_executar]();
}
```

é necessário fazer isto, porque se `janela[asp.funcao_executar]` possuir um valor atribuído e não for uma função, isto irá disparar uma exceção.

**Observações**

Como no seu `script` o `eval()` sempre acessa a variável a partir do `window`, então ele sempre vai usar uma variável global, por isto, neste caso `eval(variavel)` será igual a `window[variavel]`.

Normalmente, uso o comparador `===` para assegurar que os tipos são iguais, por exemplo `"1" == 1` retorna `true`, enquanto que `"1" === 1` retorna `false`, pois, apesar do `value: "1"` ser igual a `value: 1`, o `type: string` é diferente do `type: int`.

Caso tenha permanecido alguma dúvida, sinta-se livre para perguntar.

Comment: Acho que deves seguir essa orientação @pnet

Comment: @pnet, realizei algumas explicações, espero que agora tenha entendido um pouco da logica que apliquei para tentar melhorar a legibilidade do script.

Comment: @TobyMosque, cara, está dando form01 como undefined. Eu tenho três opções e não duas, ou seja, o ShowModalDialog, o window.open e o Modal que utilizamos. Por isso form01 está vindo undefined, mas eu declarei as três opções. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form01' of undefined

Comment: `janela` está com a `window` que chamou a pagina?